# ActiveRecord Migration to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration

Can I create an ActiveRecord Migration without `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 and Ruby on Rails 4.2.
How can I do it? I have been searching but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can.

But you should probably include them as these special columns are useful.

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html for how these columns are included.

Specifying `t.timestamps null: false` in the migration file will include the two special columns - `created_at` and `updated_at`. These special columns are automatically managed by Active Record if they exist.

So if you want to deliberately exclude these columns, remove the `t.timestamps null: false` line after the migration is generated.

Comment: It is usefull but I have a specific table that I don't need those attributes. Thanks!